# Why does Kaseya's reporting mechanism for tickets make you specify the date ranges twice?

Tags: kaseya

In the Info Center in Kaseya, when I create a new report about my tickets, I have to specify the date range for the tickets twice;

Once when I build the report, specifying the criteria and once when I run the report, this is completely redundant.

When I build the report:
[image]

[image]

When I run the report:
[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the report, in the TIME RANGE TYPE, you have to set FIXED RANGE, this way the system will not ask you for the dates at the time to run the report

Kaseya Support

Comment: Ah so you mean in the `Edit Table Data Part` window in the `Filtering` `(step 3 of 3)` section under the `Date Filter` in the `Time Range Type*:` dropdown, you want me to select `Fixed Range`?